# Montagem do MPDF com php foreach , bootstrap e html

Tags: php, foreach, mpdf

Estou tentando gerar o MPDF, mas esta aparecendo esse erro:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Esse erro esta acusando na segunda linha que é o primeiro `foreach`.

```
$prova = unserialize($row['prova']);

$html = " <div class='row'>
            ".foreach($prova[0] as $idPergunta => $rowPergunta) {."
              <div class='col-sm-6'>
                  <div class='row'>
                      <div class=''>
                          <div class='form-group'>
                              <h4><b>".echo $rowPergunta;."</b></h4>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class='row'>
                      <div class=''>
                          <div class='form-group'>
                              ".foreach($prova[1][$idPergunta] as $rowRespostas) {."
                                ".echo $rowRespostas;."
                              "}"
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

                ".$rowCount++;
                if($rowCount % $numOfCols == 0) echo '</div><div class='row'>';
                $i++; }."

            ".}."
          </div>
        ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está concatenando um `foreach`, e isso é um erro de sintaxe. `foreach` não é uma expressão ou método para poder ser concatenado. O ideal neste cenário, é dispor o conteúdo do `foreach` diretamente na string `$html`:

```php
$prova = unserialize($row['prova']);

$html = " <div class='row'>
            <?php foreach($prova[0] as $idPergunta => $rowPergunta) { ?>
              <div class='col-sm-6'>
                  <div class='row'>
                      <div class=''>
                          <div class='form-group'>
                              <h4><b><?php echo $rowPergunta . '<br/>'; ?></b></h4>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class='row'>
                      <div class=''>
                          <div class='form-group'>
                              <?php foreach($prova[1][$idPergunta] as $rowRespostas)
                                 echo $rowRespostas . <br/>;
                              } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

                <?php
                $rowCount++;
                if($rowCount % $numOfCols == 0) 
                      echo '</div><div class=\'row\'>';
                $i++;

            } ?>
          </div>
        ";
```

Este código fará um **pós-processamento** assim que `echo $html;` for efetuada. Desta maneira, o código irá executar após o procedimento.

> ### Atualização do cenário
>
> O método `WriteHTML` da lib [MPDF](http://%20github.com/mpdf/mpdf) imprime um código em HTML somente, e o PHP não é executado. Portanto, **pós-processamento não funciona nesta ocasião**.

Você também pode fazer com **pré-processamento**, assim, o HTML já vem puro e pronto, sem o PHP embutido:

```php
$html = "<div class='row'>";

foreach($prova[0] as $idPergunta => $rowPergunta) {
    $html .= "<div class='col-sm-6'>
                  <div class='row'>
                      <div class=''>
                          <div class='form-group'>
                              <h4><b>".echo $rowPergunta;."</b></h4>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class='row'>
                      <div class=''>
                          <div class='form-group'>";

    foreach($prova[1][$idPergunta] as $rowRespostas)
        $html .= $rowRespostas . "<br/>";
    }

    $html .= "</div> </div> </div> </div>";

    $rowCount++;
    if($rowCount % $numOfCols == 0) 
         $html .= "</div><div class='row'>";
    $i++;
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua ajuda. Usando o primeiro exemplo, esta aparecendo esse erro `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$rowPergunta'`.

Comment: Optei pelo primeiro, pelo fato da indentação ficar visualmente melhor.

Comment: Não prestei atenção e tinha uma linha que estava sendo processada no código antes de passar para o texto. Corrigi na edição.

Comment: Veja como esta aparecendo https://prnt.sc/oz933u

Comment: A saída deste `$html` vai para um interpretador que suporta PHP? Pelo visto, parece que não. Neste caso, você terá que utilizar o pré-processamento.

Comment: Estou usando o https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

Comment: O Segundo deu certo!

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Unica coisa que não esta acontecendo é a formatação em duas colunas. Sabe informar o motivo?